# How do I run via-IR in remix?

Tags: solidity

I am trying to write a code in solidity. However, I cannot solve stack too deep error. how can I fix this annoying problem? Remix advices to compile code by via-ir. how can I complie my code using ViaIR?

I am trying to do a code for secuirty protocols.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own configuration file for the Solidity compiler in Remix, here are [instruction](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compile.html#advanced-compiler-configurations) on how to enable this option.

Once enabled, the `compiler_config.json` file will appear in your root folder and in it you need to add the following code:

```
"settings": {
    "viaIR": true,
     ... rest of settings
}
```